# What is the best IP subnet to avoid subnet collisions?

Tags: subnet, tcpip

My company installs specialized webservers for tracking commercial building HVAC performance.  These machines each have two LAN adapters--a primary and a secondary.

The way the system is intended to work, only one port is supposed to be able to access external network segments--the system only supports a single default gateway between both ports, rather than maintaining a separate gateway for each individual adapter.  When resolving addresses, the server first checks whether the destination IP shares a subnet with either adapter, then sends external traffic to the default gateway using whichever adapter resides on the same subnet as the gateway.  This creates problems if both adapters reside on the same subnet, because the device doesn't know which adapter to forward external traffic to.

In general, my company has control over the addressing of the secondary port while our customers provide us with the addressing for the primary port so they can access it on their corporate LAN.

In an ideal world, I would set that secondary port to a standard IP configuration so that our field techs could directly connect to any server we install and not have to reconfigure their clients depending on where they are working.

As it currently stands, our current company IP address standard is 192.168.1.100/24 for the secondary port, except in all those places where the customer kept their local LAN segment on the default 192.168.1.x/24 and our standard goes out the window.

I want to change my company standard to avoid these subnet collisions so we don't have to track which sites are exceptions to the standard, but I need to know: what subnet configuration am I least likely to run into?  192.168.1.X is an obvious one, but in my experience I've run into a lot of 10.x.x.x and 172.18.x.x.  Are these the only major ranges I need to avoid?  Is there another address range that I could comfortably move our standard to because common practice among network administrators is to avoid it?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a consensus on which of the [Private address space](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) networks are most/least used. It's totally at the whim of whomever implemented the network at that site.

Comment: Why does the webserver have to network interfaces? That isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @joeqwerty The way I read it, one port is meant to be accessed internally, and the other port is meant to be accessed from the Internet.

Comment: And, this is your official reminder that this problem does not exist in IPv6, and even if you (or your customers) don't have it now, you should make sure that your hardware is ready for it when you and your customers do get it.

Comment: There are also link local addresses 169.254.0.0/16 for IPv4 and  FE80::/64 for IPv6.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want the primary NIC to be configurable as a network client, and the secondary NIC to have a static IP... because... you don't want people to change the IP... because... you want your techs to be able to connect to it... but you don't want it to conflict with any popular subnets... Why not just label the secondary port as "do not use; service port only."? If the secondary port is used for more than just service, then why not leave it configurable? It sounds like you guys have an product engineering issue.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong; your appliance has a service port used on-site by your service staff. The IPs are only used on-site and do not connect back to your corporate network. Optimally for you, each appliance would have exactly the same service-side network config at every customer site. The server cannot run DHCP or ipv6 of any kind. Your service application cannot be made smart enough to autodetect the service-side IP based on broadcast/multicast. You cannot use policy routing or ip-specific route with a device attached (eg. `route add resolver.ip.ad.dr/32 gateway cust.con.fig.gw dev eth0`)

Comment: I'm with Brian, I think  a small CIDR on the top of the link-local range is your best bet.From my reading the network is entirely local. I.e. The networks scope is just to connect onsite field techs to NIC that's reserved for this purpose.

Comment: @Brian I think the intention was to get a static address. Link-local addresses for IPv4 doesn't give you that, because they are generated randomly each time. I am not so sure that IPv4 implementations can even deal with having two links with link-local addresses. With IPv6 you can have a static link-local address based on your MAC address, then you can access it even if you forgot how you configured the network on the box and link-local often keeps working when your network configuration is broken. However if you are using a web interface beware that many browsers don't support link-local.

Comment: kasperd's answer is probably the closest you'll get to a low chance of collision. However, you could also use a 192.168.X class C address with X in the upper middle range - say 173 for 192.168.173/24 - which is possibly less likely to be used. But in general, there is just not a lot of room in the IPv4 private address space

Answer (score 4):

You can use `fdc8:6837:6e34:2b0c::/64` to avoid collisions. It is highly unlikely that anybody else is using that exact prefix.

That prefix was generated according to RFC 4193. The way RFC 4193 works is that you start with `fd` as the first octet, the next five octets must be randomly generated. The randomness of those five octets ensures that you will only have a negligible probability of collisions.

That approach will produce a `/48` prefix, and you are allowed to use the remaining 80 bits as you see fit. In the example above I chose to generate the next 16 bits randomly as well to reduce the probability of collisions even further.

If you insist on using IPv4 (which I would not recommend because IPv6 is better suited to the requirements you mention than IPv4 is), you can still take some inspiration from RFC 4193. When choosing an RFC 1918 prefix, you can generate some octets in the address randomly. You are not required to use a `/24`. Judging from your requirements, I think a `/29` prefix could be more suitable. So you can take `10.0.0.0/8` and append 21 random bits, which could end up as `10.123.71.152/29`.

The risk of a collision if you use that prefix will be fairly low, but it will still be higher than with IPv6.

Comment: There are a few other possibilities, but they are potentially problematic, so I left them out of this answer. I can update the answer to include such information, if anybody think it is important.

Comment: Hasn't there been enough RFC violation for one lifetime? :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure. If I were to mention other possibilities I would of course include information about what the relevant RFCs say, and explain why those requirements would be a challenge.

Comment: *"The risk of a collision if you use that prefix will be fairly low"* - the amount of times I've seen `10.0.0.x/8` used for a small network, I think the  chance of *a single* collision at some point is quite high...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Though you could technically call that a collision, it wouldn't be a problem unless one of the addresses from the `/29` was actually used on the other network. Addresses within the `/29` will be used on one interface due to a more specific route, and the rest of `10.0.0.0/8` will be used on the other interface. And I don't see any way to do any better than this with IPv4.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I've seen places which do that too (my local nerd bar which fails the "nerd" part in this one respect), but that's really only a problem if you're trying to VPN into a network that also pushes a /8. kasperd is correct here: use IPv6, or use the smallest arbitrary RFC 1918 network that is sized to your company's immediate growth needs.

Comment: While including specific examples can be helpful, doesn't it sort of defeat the purpose of generating a random prefix when the example is posed as the answer? My mind went in the direction of https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Of course there does exist a risk that multiple persons will copy the example verbatim and eventually cause a collision from doing so. I do however think that the risk of collisions caused that way is smaller than the risk of collisions caused by whatever those people would have done instead. Lots of people violate RFC 4193 by setting all five octets to zero instead of generating them randomly. I wonder if stackexchange has any functionality I could use to make my example appear different to every user.

Answer (score 1):

There are several non-Internet-routable IPv4 address ranges, other than the RFC 1918 Private Address ranges, from which to choose. The three TEST-NET ranges come to mind immediately. Check out the [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml).

Comment: Sorry about earlier, I mixed up my browser tabs and honestly believed I was citing a BCP. I asked the mods to clean up the earlier discussion. The only disclaimer required here is coordinating with your fellow network operators: it's common (enough) practice to include these ranges in [BOGON lists](http://www.team-cymru.org/bogon-dotted-decimal.html), but so long as everyone is on the same page there are no standards or BCPs that would stand in the way of this.